# how add text from stream when I send email in C

Tags: c, email, stream

I try write program which sending email, it works, but there is no body from stream in this email. Could you tell me how I can put string from stream to my email?

```
void sendmail() {
char command[255];
sprintf(command, "echo '' | mail -v -s 'Message from process PID %d' %s",               getpid(), EMAIL);
printf("%s\n", command);
shellcmd(command);
}

int main () {
int fd[2];
pid_t pid;
pipe(fd);
pid = fork();
sendmail();
if (pid == (pid_t) 0) {
    /* child */
    close(fd[1]);
    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[0]);
    execlp("sort", "sort", 0);
} else if (pid > 0) {
    FILE * stream;
    close(fd[0]);
    stream = fdopen(fd[1], "w");
    fprintf(stream, "Witam.\n");
    fflush(stream);
    close(fd[1]);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: `echo ''` means you set an empty body. If you want a body, then you can set it there.

Comment: ok so what i should put there to use text from stream?

Comment: system(' echo test | mail nmmm@domain.com ');

this is minimal example. but I suggest you do it with popen()

I can publish this as answer, but i do not understand the question completly.

Comment: also is this an exercise or system administration script? if is second, just do it with /bin/sh. you have stdin read, feed to something, read in child, feed to sort etc... for me it looks like   cat | sort | mail ?

Comment: I would like that email have text from stream  - fprintf(stream, "Hello.\n"); I don't know how transfer stream to mail (body). This is a exercise.